# Trouble linking JS objects to HTML div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a group of JS objects which represent individual cards in a deck. I have an HTML file with div classes for each card. I am just not sure what I need to type into the div class to link it with an object.

Here is an example of one **object:**

```
threeOfClubs= {
    name : '3 of Clubs',
    suit : 'Club',
    value : 3,
    image : '3C.png'
}
```

I want my div class to link to this object so I can display the png on a webpage. Here is how the div classes look.

**HTML**

```
<div class="card">

</div>
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: There is nothing common between the element and the object to link them.

Comment: I've tried researching how to link JS and HTML but I couldn't find anything specific to objects. I am not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

What you'd do is this:

```
var card = document.getElementsByClassName("card")[0];
card.style.background-image = threeOfClubs.image;
```

This sets the CSS `backgruond-image` property to the property `image` in the `threeOfClubs` object.